# subscribe as last method raised

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Is there a way to subscribe a method though it would be called last when the onNext is raised?

```
m_subject.Subscribe(() => Console.writeLine("firstSubscription");
m_subject.SubscribeLast(() => Console.writeLine("secondSubscription");
m_subject.Subscribe(() => Console.writeLine("thirdSubscription");

m_subject.OnNext();

// prints:
// firstSubscription
// thirdSubscription
// secondSubscription
```

Comment: Can you please explain further? Not quite sure what you trying to do!

Comment: I have a method which disposes a resource. It must be called last after all registered methods have been called and used the resource. I do not know the sequence of subscriptions

Comment: All the code you put, is it on one single method?

Comment: I would have a helper class (ResourceManager or something) that wraps the resource and manages the subscribers to the resource. When there are no more subscribers it disposes the resource. Then get your RX queries to register themselves with the resource and unregister when they've finished with it.

Comment: Generally I would suggest that the values of an Observable sequence (`IObservable<T>`) should be immutable data types. This to me would suggest that they should not have mutating/side effecting behaviours like resource disposal. Maybe you want to look at a different design, or expand on the specifics of your problem so better guidance can be provided

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have a subscriber be executed last, but you can wrap all your calls in a single subscription.

Something like that:

```
Action action = () => {};
Action lastAction = () => {};

m_subject.Subscribe(() => 
{
    action();
    lastAction();
});

action += (() => Console.writeLine("firstSubscription");
lastAction += (() => Console.writeLine("secondSubscription");
action += (() => Console.writeLine("thirdSubscription");

m_subject.OnNext();

// prints:
// firstSubscription
// thirdSubscription
// secondSubscription
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by defining a custom `Subject<T>` which internally has a default subject and also a last subject.

**Update**

I added overloads of `ObserveOn` to store the `IScheduler` and `SynchronizationContext` and then apply those at the time of subscription. Similar technique can be used to enable `SubscribeOn` to work as well.

```
public class SubscribeLastSubject<T> : ISubject<T>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Subject<T> subject = new Subject<T>();
    private readonly Subject<T> lastSubject = new Subject<T>();
    private IScheduler observeScheduler;
    private SynchronizationContext observerContext;

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        subject.OnNext(value);
        lastSubject.OnNext(value);
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        subject.OnError(error);
        lastSubject.OnError(error);
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        subject.OnCompleted();
        lastSubject.OnCompleted();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        return GetObservable().Subscribe(observer);           
    }

    public IDisposable SubscribeLast(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        return GetLastObservable().Subscribe(observer);     
    }

    public IDisposable SubscribeLast(Action<T> action)
    {
        return GetLastObservable().Subscribe(action);
    }

    public SubscribeLastSubject<T> ObserveOn(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        observeScheduler = scheduler;
        return this;
    }

    public SubscribeLastSubject<T> ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext context)
    {
        observerContext = context;
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        subject.Dispose();
        lastSubject.Dispose();
    }

    private IObservable<T> GetObservable()
    {
        if (observerContext != null)
        {
            return subject.ObserveOn(observerContext);
        }

        if (observeScheduler != null)
        {
            return subject.ObserveOn(observeScheduler);
        }

        return subject;
    }

    private IObservable<T> GetLastObservable()
    {
        if (observerContext != null)
        {
            return lastSubject.ObserveOn(observerContext);
        }

        if (observeScheduler != null)
        {
            return lastSubject.ObserveOn(observeScheduler);
        }

        return lastSubject;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var m_subject = new SubscribeLastSubject<string>();

m_subject.ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread).Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine("firstSubscription"));
m_subject.ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread).SubscribeLast(s => Console.WriteLine("secondSubscription"));
m_subject.ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread).Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine("thirdSubscription"));

m_subject.OnNext("1");

Console.ReadKey();
```

**Output**

```
firstSubscription
thirdSubscription
secondSubscription
```

Comment: Could you explain how exactly are these going to help?

Comment: This solution is good but I can not use ObserveOn for it. Do you have a solution to do: m_subject.ObserveOn(...).SubscribeLast(...);